# Profile image doesn't remain saved and fit correctly

Tags: flutter

I am making the profile page , and i don't understand why the image that i choose doesn't remain saved and fit correctly in the spot.I used this code for upload image

```
Future _getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    });
  }
    Future uploadPic(BuildContext context) async {
        String fileName = basename(_image.path);
        StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
            FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
        StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
        StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
        setState(() {
          print("Profile Picture uploaded");
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text('Profile Picture Uploaded'),
          ));
        });
      }
```

but i don't know how i can i called the function here to be saved automatically

```
child: Container(
                  height: 84,
                  width: 84,

                  //profilepic
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: _getImage,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 100,
                        child: ClipOval(
                          child: (_image != null)
                              ? Image.file(
                                  _image,
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                )
                              : Image.network(
                                  'https://icon-library.com/images/add-image-icon/add-image-icon-14.jpg',
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                ),
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
```

And when i choose a photo it doesn't fit correctly and it looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I re-read your question, and in order to call your `uploadPic()` function, make the `onTap` function like so:

```
onTap: (){
  uploadPic(context);
}
```

As for the rest of the code, I need to know what CircleAvatar looks like and _getImage is.

Comment: it disappear all when i use this code instead of CircleAvatar

Comment: i put a photo , the circle avatar is blue one and the getImage opens the gallery to choose a photo and it doesn't fit it correctly